# -ADVICE REQUEST- MS-ACCESS Hyperlink Comparison Script Advice

Tags: database, ms-access, hyperlink

I'm brand new to MS-Access and had a few guideline-questions,

My organization uses MS-Access to track a large electronic-part inventory. These parts have a hyperlink field that links to the product webpage. Here's an example:

```
Part Number     Part Type    Value  Description                 Component_Height    Voltage Tolerance   Schematic Part              Layout PCB Footprint    Manufacturer Part Number    Manufacturer    Distributor Part Number Distributor Price   Availability    Link
UMK105CG100DV-F Ceramic      10pF   CAP CER 10PF 50V NP0 0402   0.35 MM             50V     ±0.5pF      xxxxx\C_NP,xxxxx\C_NP_Small c_0402                  UMK105CG100DV-F             Taiyo Yuden     587-1947-2-ND    Digi-Key          0.00378  In Stock        http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/UMK105CG100DV-F/587-1947-2-ND/1473246
```

Links Here:

http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/UMK105CG100DV-F/587-1947-2-ND/1473246

Nearly the entire majority of our hyperlinks point to the supplier DigiKey.

Right now the verification flow goes like this:

Every month or so a large group of us sits down and one by one copies the hyperlink into google.
We then open the corresponding webpage and verify component availability etc.

We have nearly 1000 components and this process takes hours. All I'm looking for is advice on how to improve our workflow. I was hoping there was say a way to write a "open hyperlink with default browser and search string" macro or scripting interface. The pseudo-script would then check that the string "Quantity Available" was greater than 1, and if it wasn't (the part was out of stock) mark the part as obsolete.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, I'm really aiming to optimize our workflow.

Answer (score 2):

You can traverse the DOM of the web page. A quick look at the web page and you can see a table with a name of product-details.

So the following VBA code would load the sample web page, and pull out the values.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Enum READYSTATE

   READYSTATE_UNINITIALIZED = 0
   READYSTATE_LOADING = 1
   READYSTATE_LOADED = 2
   READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE = 3
   READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4

End Enum

Sub GetWebX()

  Dim ie      As New InternetExplorer
  Dim HTML    As New HTMLDocument
  Dim strURL  As String
  Dim Htable  As New HTMLDocument
  Dim i       As Integer

  strURL = "http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/UMK105CG100DV-F/587-1947-2-ND/1473246"

  ie.Navigate strURL
  Do While ie.READYSTATE < READYSTATE_COMPLETE
     DoEvents
  Loop
  Set HTML = ie.Document

  Set Htable = HTML.getElementById("product-details")

  For i = 0 To Htable.Rows.Length - 1
     With Htable.Rows(i)
        Debug.Print Trim(.Cells(0).innerText), Trim(.Cells(1).innerText)
     End With
  Next I
  ie.Quit
  Set ie = Nothing

End Sub
```

output of above:

```
Digi-Key Part Number           587-1947-2-ND
Quantity Available             230,000 
 Can ship immediately
Manufacturer                   Taiyo Yuden
Manufacturer Part Number       UMK105CG100DV-F
Description                    CAP CER 10PF 50V NP0 0402
Expanded Description           10pF ±0.5pF 50V Ceramic Capacitor C0G, NP0 0402(1005 Metric)
Lead Free Status / RoHS Status Lead free / RoHS Compliant
Moisture Sensitivity Level (MSL)  1 (Unlimited)
Manufacturer Standard Lead Time   11 Weeks
```

Since the above is a array, then you could place a button right on the form, and have a few extra lines of VBA to write the values into the form. So a user would just have to go to the given record/form in Access - press a button and the above values would be copied right into the form.

the above VBA code requires a reference to:

```
Microsoft Internet Controls
Microsoft HTML Object Library
```

I would suggest that after testing you use late binding for the above two libraries.